# Apache Permission denied to connect to socket

Tags: c++, c, apache, sockets

I am using sys/socket.h. When I try to make a socket connection in Apache server environment. It fails to make a socket connection with Permission Defined Errno 13.
Is there some permission that I need to give to apache.

Thanks!!

Comment: This might help you: [13PermissionDenied](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied), but some code would really help us.

Answer (score 2):

*Temporally* disable SELinux and see what happens:

Edit `/etc/selinux/config` as root and change the SELINUX line to `SELINUX=disabled`. If this fixes your problems, you should reenable SELinux and get in contact with the policy writers (i.e. file a bug report at your distributions bugtracker).

Thanks for the edit Jonas ;)

A couple of months ago I had a similar problem with a Fedora server, just had to run `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1` to fix

Comment: If you recommend to disable selinux, please also mention the sideeffects. Many people don't really know what it does, so it's worth pointing that out _especially_ in the context of web services.

Comment: @JonasWielicki do you understand the meaning of temporally?

Comment: Good point — I actually managed to overlook that. I feel sorry for the downvote; I added a few lines to be able to remove the downvote (can only remove after edit).

Comment: Note that there are more fine-grained bools, e.g. if you need SMTP, there is a special bool for that.

Comment: I thing that `setenforce 0` is much better to disable selinux temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to `bind()` a socket to a port below 1024 you need superuser rights.

When trying to `connect()`, `EACCES` (13) might be returned if a local firewall prohibits the connection.